# Where is .htaccess on AWS EC2 EB

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an EC2 instance running Elastic Beanstalk.  I would like to enable GZIP Compression, and I understand I need to modify my `.htaccess` file.

I have read that the `.htaccess` file is located in my root folder of the app install.  However, I cannot seem to find it. (I am pretty novice and not sure where the root folder is).

I am able to ssh onto the server running Apache Tomcat 8 with a Java 8 app.

**Question**

Where is `.htaccess` located?

This is what I have in my root:

```
$ ls
bin   cgroup  etc   lib    local       media  opt   root  sbin     srv  tmp  var
boot  dev     home  lib64  lost+found  mnt    proc  run   selinux  sys  usr
```

**UPDATE**

I have a `.ebextensions/tomcat-settings.config` now that works. It enables GZip compression.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    GzipCompression: 'true'
    ProxyServer: nginx
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /pub: public
```

This does not seem to compress `.svg` files though.  So if possible, I would like to have the following, but not sure where to add it:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with beanstalk but try adding the -a switch to ls since the .htaccess is a hidden file. ls -a allows you to see all files including hidden ones.

Answer (score 0):

you need to upload .htaccess file or make it in your ec2 instance on your root folder on that you upload your application, if you are using elastick beanstalk you need to add the .htaccess file to your .zip file on the root folder

Comment: Hi Brayan, thanks for the advise. I added `.htaccess` to the root of `src/main/webapp`. This means when I do `mvn install` it is build to the root of my `war` file. Then deploying to the Tomcat server. But when I test the page, it's not compressed. When I `ssh` onto the server, I find it at `./tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/.htaccess`. (I add the following to my `.htaccess` file: https://www.clayharmon.com/words/posts/enabling-gzip-compression-on-ec2). Do you know why it's not compressing the page?

Comment: I followed the following advise, and it works for me. (added a `tomcat-settings.config` file to the `webapp` root) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html

Answer (score 0):

How you configured the ec2 instance, by ssh or by the .ebextensions file?
if you configure the instance by ssh and you are using a elastic enviorment  then the configuration will be erased when the instance is degraded or change, if you are using only one instance by  ec2 the configuration keep working.

if you need to configure it by .ebextensions you need to create a folder named .ebextensions in your .zip file, inside this folder you need to create two files named enable_mod_deflate.conf and myapp.config.

**The contents of enable_mod_deflate.conf:**

```
  # mod_deflate configuration
  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Restrict compression to these MIME types
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml+rss
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg

  # Level of compression (Highest 9 - Lowest 1)
  DeflateCompressionLevel 9

  # Netscape 4.x has some problems.
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

  # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

  # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
  BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
  </IfModule>

  </IfModule>
```

**The contents of myapp.config:**

```
  container_commands:
      01_setup_apache:
          command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
```

**Then you need to restart the server.**

Comment: Hi Brayan, thanks for the comprehensive answer. I do already have a `.ebextensions/tomcat-settings.config` file, that does GZip compression successfully (see UPDATE above). So, I add the `enable_mod_deflate.conf` & `myapp.config` as you suggest above. However, when I run Google PageSpeed Insights over my website (www.thewhozoo.com), I don't get any improvements.